# Django: return HTML file including script

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am working on a single page application called 'bookMarks' using HTML+CSS+jQuery as the front end and Django as my back end. I created a Django project and put my app.html+app.js+app.css+jquery.js in /static.

My question is: I would like my view to return the app.html as it should be without using Django template. I have tried this:

```
#app/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, HttpResponse
import urllib
def index(request):
    index = urllib.urlopen('static/app.html').read()
    return HttpResponse(index)

#static/app.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>My Bookmarks</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="app.js">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">
        Easy-Save Bookmarks
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <h3 class="tag">News</h3>
            <div>
                <p> A book mark here!</p>
            </div>
        <h3 class="tag">Reading</h3>
            <div>
                <p> A book mark here!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="newTag"></div>
            <div>
                <form name="addTagForm">
                    <input type="text" name="newTag">
                    <input id="addTag" type="button" value="Add a new tag">
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

But it seems that all JS and CSS effects are ignored.

Could someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Why do that? What is wrong with properly rendering a template?

Comment: Yes that's my second choice to render a template, but I always want to know if there is some simple way to do that without templates. So I don't waste the html files that I have writen.

Comment: What could be simpler than rendering a template in Django? How are existing html files wasted?

Comment: You can just use your app.html as the template without chaning anything - that would shorten your views.py to a onliner. However, I doubt that the js and css will be found: the paths have to be set to src='/static/apps.js'

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that's because I didn't include my js+css files in the absolute way.

Now when I put my HTML+JS+CSS files in my_app/static/, and include absolute 
    
The view will return my html correctly.